# How can I stop webpack from polluting my folders with .js and .js.map files?

Tags: visual-studio, webpack

I recently setup webpack for an app I write.

This is my config:

```
var path = require("path");
const statements = require('tsx-control-statements').default;

const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        bundle: "./React/index.ts",
        logonBundle: "./React/logonIndex.ts",
        otherBundle: "./React/otherEntryPoint.ts",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/dist/")
    },
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "less-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    getCustomTransformers: () => ({ before: [statements()] })
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({configFile: "./tsconfig.json"})],
        modules: ["node_modules"]
    },
};
```

This works perfectly fine, but what I don't like is how webpack pollutes my folders with the transpiled files.

For every .ts and .tsx file, I have the following output now:

[image]

How can I get rid of this? Or, better said, where did I go wrong with my config? I'm sure it has to do with the sourcemap, but I can't figure out how to get around it.

EDIT: What's quite interesting... This only happens when I build from Visual Studio. It doesn't happen when building directly via CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not webpack, but Visual Studio.

Turns out, my VS did some build on its own as well. I added

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to my csproj and now it doesn't pollute my folders anymore.